# Concatenate lines of file

Tags: bash, line

I am having these two lines and I am trying to get all in one line as a variable in bash.

initial values

```
DEST
none
```

and I would like such of result:

```
DEST="none"
```

Many thanks in advance for any suggestion,

Al.

Comment: Does your input consist of *only* two lines, or you have more and need to do that for each pair of lines ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `paste` command for that:

```
echo -e "DEST\nnone" | paste -s -d '='
```

or

```
cat <file> | paste -s -d '='
```

Comment: What about the quotes, in case the second line contains whitespace: `DEST="multi word value"` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `awk` command:

```
awk '!(NR%2){print s,$1}NR%2{s=$1}' OFS== <file>
```

Depending of the contents of file, you might need to enclose the value (every second line) in quotes:

```
awk '!(NR%2){print s,"\""$1"\""}NR%2{s=$1}' OFS== <file>
```

This would give you:

```
DEST="none"
```